# What should you do when 2 or more users post almost simultaneously the correct answer?

Tags: support

You ask a question. Eventually 2 or more users post, almost simultaneously, the correct answer. Both answers are equally good and descriptive. What criterion should you use to select the correct answer?

Comment: Oh no! @gnat now that I think about it that doesn't answer exactly what I'm asking for. But whatever, I guess I can't redo it now. It is a very similar question anyway.

Comment: if two answers are totally equally good and arrived at almost the same time, accept one that arrived _later_. That way, you will make life of [meta-tag:fastest-gun] folks harder

Comment: ...alternatively, you can accept answer that arrived earlier, if you prefer to incentivize this behavior

Comment: you select your own *accepted* answer, not the singular correct answer. They're both correct, after all, your choice is not going to change that. You should make up your own mind, I've seen people reason to pick the person with the lowest amount of internet points to "help" them for example.

Comment: I almost want to ask that this question be reopened since it is somewhat unique to the linked duplicate because it considers temporality; but I suppose the answers to either question are the same.